# How to get the quota kernel modules on the AWS kernel?

Tags: apt, kernel, amazon-ec2, quota

I can't seem to be able to install the quota modules for the Ubuntu 16.04 AWS kernel.   I've started the official cloud image (`ami-e5d9439a` from [Ubuntu's Cloud Images site](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)).   Checking for the kernel modules shows that they're not installed:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ modprobe quota_v1
modprobe: FATAL: Module quota_v1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-1060-aws
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ modprobe quota_v2
modprobe: FATAL: Module quota_v2 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-1060-aws
```

The normal trick to get the quota modules is to install the linux-image-extra package for your kernel, but that doesn't exist for this one:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ sudo apt-get update
...
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1060-aws
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1060-aws'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1060-aws'
```

Installing the `linux-image-extra-virtual` doesn't help, of course, because everything it installs is for the wrong kernel version:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amd64-microcode crda intel-microcode iucode-tool iw libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 linux-firmware linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic linux-image-generic thermald wireless-regdb
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amd64-microcode crda intel-microcode iucode-tool iw libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 linux-firmware linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic linux-image-extra-virtual linux-image-generic thermald wireless-regdb
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 110 MB of archives.
After this operation, 456 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] yes
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnl-3-200 amd64 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1 [52.2 kB]
...
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ sudo reboot
...
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-0-78 4.4.0-1060-aws #69-Ubuntu SMP Sun May 20 13:42:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ modprobe quota_v1
modprobe: FATAL: Module quota_v1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-1060-aws
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-78:~$ modprobe quota_v2
modprobe: FATAL: Module quota_v2 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-1060-aws
```

Is there a package I can install to get the quota kernel modules?   Or do I have to build them myself if I want disk quotas on an AWS machine?

Comment: I have the same error trying to run quota on Ubuntu 18 on Google Compute Engine instance: `modprobe: FATAL: Module quota_v1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-1026-gcp`

Comment: There is a bugreport on launchpad for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws/+bug/1773172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: **install the `linux-modules-extra-aws` package**.

I've spent a lot of time on this and the answer was hidden among the comments of the question itself.

> There is a bugreport on launchpad for this [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws/+bug/1773172](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux%20aws/+bug/1773172) – MrSpock Mar
> 12 '19 at 14:12

Hope this helps others as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- upvoted and accepted :-)  That is indeed the way to fix the issue now; that package didn't exist back when I asked originally back in 2018, but was added some time after.